# Which form of verbs should be used after conjuction words in interrogative statements?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, verb-forms

Which sentence is correct?

1. Why did you close that and open this?!
2. Why did you close that and opened this?!

When a verb comes after a conjuction word such as *and* in sentences like the above question, which form of the verb should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form, *Why did you close that and open this?* is correct.  (The use of both the question mark and the exclamation point together is non-standard, though.)

Interrogative sentences in the past tense are formed by **did** + *unmarked infinitive*.  It may be easier to see the pattern if you split the question into two sentences:

- Why did you close that?
- Why did you open this?